# Return by value or reference?

Tags: c#, return-value, ref

If we have two methods, one returning a variable by value, and the other by reference, which has the highest performance?

```
myObj.Method1(out var);
```

or

```
var = myObj.Method2();
```

I guess the first version is more efficient but, does that mean you should always build methods that return values by reference? Or is there any reason to return variables by value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The performance difference will be immeasurably small or nonexistent.

You are incorrectly assuming that the two versions have different semantics.
For reference types, both methods will copy a reference exactly once.

For large value types, `out` parameters can be faster, since you don't need  a separate temporary local.
*Always measure before jumping to conclusions*!

Do not use `out` parameters unless you need to return 2 values.

Comment: But if I am working with XNA and I have to return a Matrix type, it's better to use the first form?

Comment: The first form (out var) is basically an exception to the *general rule*: when your method *gives* data to the caller, this should always be the return value until you have to return more than 1 parameter. Also, *out* is not to prefer because it shouldn't be CLS compatible, ie. new languages for CLR might not support this form of parameter return. I'm verifying if my statement about CLS is correct right now...

Comment: Ok, basically I only have to use the first form in case I have 2 return values o a large value type, right?

Comment: Yes.  (And only if you've measured it and found a perf hit)

Comment: Okas. Thanks for the answers ^^

Answer (score 4):

There is absolutely no performance difference as long as they are reference type.

By the way, if you define your method so that it returns a value, this will **not** be by value. Return type is always is by reference unless the type is a value type.

Answer (score 1):

There will be little to no difference for reference types (classes), because in both cases it the value is returned by reference.

For value types (structs) there might be a difference if the type contains many fields, in that case returning using the `out` parameter is a bit faster.